# java: need to pass arg to thread run() without using the contractor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I want to have something like that:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
  int y;

  public WorkerThread(int y) {
    this.y = y;

  }

  @Override
  public void run(int x) {
    System.out.println(x+y);
  }
}
```

in main

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    for (int num: number) {
        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(num);
        for (int  anotherNum : anotherNumbers) {
                executor.execute(worker.run(anotherNum));
        }
    }
```

I want to have thread for each number and I want to run it with an argument of another number.

I cannot do it because run() does not take an argument in its signature.

what other options do I have?

Please, don't ask me why I need it or try to question the reasons I am using threads here.

Comment: That's the Runnable API; you can't change it.    Constructor and objects are your only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>How you're trying to do this is impossible. You'll want to do this instead:</strike>

```
class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    int x, y;
    public WorkerThread(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(x+y);
    }
}
```

Then, when you're calling the code to run it:

```
for (int num: number) {
    WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread(num); //worker.y = num
    for (int  anotherNum : anotherNumbers) {
        worker.x = anotherNum; //we assign x here
        executor.execute(worker); //You call by the object, not by its method
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I changed worker to type WorkerThread, since executor.execute(Runnable) will take an object without needing an explicit cast to Runnable, so long as the object in question is an implementer of Runnable.

**DOUBLE EDIT COMBO:** Let's try a different approach, assuming you're using Java 8:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for(int num : numbers) {
    Integer x = num;
    for(int num2 : otherNumbers) {
        Integer y = num2;
        executor.execute(() -> System.out.println(x+y));
    }
}
```

This will have the precise output of your previous code without needing to define a whole class just to perform the task.

Comment: worker.x ==> compilation error since worker defined as Runnable  and Runnable  does not have x field in it.

Comment: I updated the code. worker doesn't need to be defined as Runnable, so long as the class implements Runnable.

Comment: Since the same Worker instance is used by multiple threads, I don't think we can rely on such a field of Worker class. A thread that works on this one Worker instance, has the potential of reading value that was meant for  some other Thread.

Comment: @Mecon I've added another possible solution that satisfies the concerns you brought up. Having said that though, if you need to maintain the state of these worker threads while also adhering to the requirements you described, then I don't think what you're trying to do is possible without rethinking your whole design. The object needs to be unique across all threads, or there's not much you can do to ensure the efficacy of the object across threads. My code ensures that, and if it doesn't satisfy your design requirements, then you need to revise your goal.

Comment: @Xirema  The requirements, design, goal.. that you mention, were OPs, not mine. Anyway, there is more than one way to solve this problem. Thanks adding the edit. Hopefully OP has the choice to avoid Worker instance.

Comment: @Xirema I would suggest you remove the first answer completely, because somebody else might see it as accepted answer. And they will not know its issues until the code goes to production.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
  int y;
  int x;
  public WorkerThread(int y, int x) {
    this.y = y;

  }
  public void setX (int x)
  {
    this.x=x;
  }
  @Override
  public void run(int x) {
    System.out.println(x+y);
  }
}
```

then you call setX method from within the loop, however your code wont work anyway because `executor.execute(worker.run(anotherNum));` expects a Runnable, and since run is void it wont even compile, I suggest you do the following

```
  for (int  anotherNum : anotherNumbers) {
            Worker.setX(anotherNumbers);
            executor.execute(worker);
    }
```